# Does music enhance neural activity/cognitive or cerebral function, or is it just mania?

Tags: neuroscience, cognition

I always find myself drew upon curiosity whilst studying, to whether certain types of music *are* or *are not*, effecting me in a sense of cognitive ability.

Take a fantastic piece such as, **Mozart's, Symphony No. 40 in G minor, K. 550**, for example. Whenever i'm listening to it, at the same time as studying, I feel more fluid... and somewhat enthusiastic. Is there a reason for this?

So to conclude, does music of specific  genre's (i.e. Classical) or, music in general, have any impact on cognitive performance? In particular, cognitive performance, in regards to Mathematics.

Comment: This sounds like it would be better received at [cogsci.SE](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/).